# Android Emulator Archive not displaying links

Tags: android, android-emulator

Today I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio and my emulator stopped working. After doing some researches I understood I should probably downgrade my emulator, but at the proper page in the android developer website I can't find any links to download the image, every version appears like this.

The weirdest thing is that it looks like no one else in the google-world ever had this problem

I found a repository of all the emulators but they appear with the name like "emulator-darwin_x64-7425822" and I can't find their version number anywhere (it looks that I need to put this number into the package.xml file in order to make it work)